# How do I change the input type of an exposed filter in a view?

Tags: views

I have a view which lists products. I created an exposed filter based on price criteria.

The exposed filter shows a text input where you can type an integer number to get the products filtered. What I need is to replace the text input with a select list showing values such as 50000, 100000, 1500000, 200000.

I have the [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module, and the [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module enabled.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters), you can go to the edit page for the view (from /admin/structure/views).  Then selected `Better Exposed Filters` for the `Exposed form style` which is under `EXPOSED FORM`.

Next click `BEF Settings`, scroll down to `Exposed Filter Settings`, and choose `Display "Price is higher than"` as `Select list`.  If you don't have the option for select list, the Better Exposed Filters module won't be able to help you.

Comment: No, I don't have the 'Select list' option. Why? What can I do to have this option available?

Comment: What type of field is it?  Integer?  List (integer)?

Comment: It is a Integer field type.

Comment: Can you use a list (integer) or is that impossible for your use case?  If you re-create the type as a list integer, you'll be able to display it as a select list with no problem-- however, you will have to choose all values from the list and will no longer be able to input values freely.

Comment: I see. I need to be able to freely set these values. What about programmatically? I found this article http://drupal.org/node/766974 but not sure if I will find the solution...

Comment: Sorry, you stumped me.  Hopefully someone else has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit View >> Configure filter criterion >> Select grouped filter (instead of the default, single filter) >> Set-up your options. That's it! you now have dropdown filters of free filled node field.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the situation as well. As a quick "hack" you can do the following:

1. expose your filter as a text field, just like you show above
2. copy and paste the HTML output of that filter (everything between < FORM ... and < /FORM> tags
3. add the HTML in the view's "header" as "global text area", make sure you select a text filter that allows FORM and SELECT tags
4. replace the < INPUT ..> tag with a < SELECT> tag (keep the name=... value the same)
5. add your < OPTION> tags, use value="" if you want an "Show all" option
6. hide the exposed filter by setting "exposed form in a block" to yes

Now you'll have a select list instead of an input box.
You could probably add a bit of jquery magic if you want to preselect the option.

If you have a lot of options you could probably even use another view to generate the < OPTION> tags using rewrites. However, I haven't tried that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this module: [Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter)

You create a separate view (or a new display of the same view) which returns the list of items to show in drop down select list of the exposed filter.